# How to utilize ZAP running on another machine

Tags: jenkins, zap

I am able to integrate ZAP running on another machine(let's say machine-B) with Jenkins installed on one machine (machine-A). While building a project, ZAP starts from another machine(B), but the resources(memory, heap) are utilised from one machine(A), which shouldn't be so.

Could someone suggest how to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

By default ZAP will only allow connections from the local machine. You can set which IP addresses can connect to the API using the command line:

-config api.addrs.addr.name=123.456.789.123

If you are using ZAP in a completely isolated environment you can allow all IP addresses to connect to the ZAP API using:

> -config api.addrs.addr.name=.* -config api.addrs.addr.regex=true

You will also need to set or disable the API key.

For more details see this FAQ: https://github.com/zaproxy/zaproxy/wiki/FAQremote